# How to create auto-increment number column in SharePoint 2013 from specific field wise (group field wise)

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

I need to create a custom column or calculated column to display auto increment number (like serial number) from the specific field name wise (group field wise) from the list.
For example,

List1

```
    name     type           
    ABC      merchant       
    DEF      employee
    GHI      merchant
    JKL      merchant
```

Then i want the result like,

List1

```
    name     type           SN   
    ABC      merchant       1
    DEF      employee       1
    GHI      merchant       2
    JKL      merchant       3
    MNO      employee       2
    PQR      customer       1
```

How can I achieve this from SharePoint or InfoPath Form?
Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow for item Created, when new item created, call rest api to filter based on 'type' and get count of matched items, then update SN.

[Call rest api in SharePoint designer 2013 workflow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Count rest api items count.
[image]

[SharePoint rest api filter.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35796.sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-for-selecting-filtering-sorting-and-pagination-in-sharepoint-list.aspx)